# how to commit with a message from a file

Tags: svn

We usually commit as below

```
`$ svn commit -m "added howto section."`
```

But my commit message template is too long to write on.

So I like to write commit message from a text file(commit message in it!).

Is there any solution about this?

I use `svn console`.  not `Tortoise svn`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there is a command-line option for that. Read the documentation for SVN to learn its syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [freely available online SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svn.c.commit):

> Commit a modification to the file foo.c (explicitly specified on the
>   command line) with the commit message in a file named msg:
>
> $ svn commit -F msg foo.c